# Proof Verification for M matrices

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, solution-verification

A matrix having non-negative diagonal entries and non-positive off-diagonal entries is called an M matrix. Its inverse is always non-negative. Suppose we have two positive constants $a_1$ and $a_2$ and $a_1<a_2$. Suppose the M matrix be $I-\alpha P$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $P$ is component-wise non-negative and row sum is $1$, and $\alpha\in(0,1)$. I want to know if there is any possible way that $a_1 (I-\alpha P)$ and $a_2 (I-\alpha P)$ can be compared? 
Is it correct to say: $(a_1(I-\alpha P))^{-1}\leq (a_2(I-\alpha P))^{-1}$. 
This holds as  $(I-\alpha P)^{-1}$ is non-negative and $\frac{1}{a_1}>\frac{1}{a_2}$. But without inverse it does not hold true. 
Any further suggestions or counter-example to this will be really helpful

Comment: The usual definition of an M-matrix is a real square matrix with non-positive off-diagonal entries and eigenvalues with non-negative real parts. Your definition is quite different and it is not equivalent to the usual one. E.g. $\pmatrix{0&-1\\ -1&0}$ is an M-matrix under your definition but not the usual definition.

Comment: Anyway, since $\rho(\alpha P)=\alpha<1$ the matrix inverse $(I-\alpha P)^{-1}$ can be expanded as a Neumann series $I+\alpha P+(\alpha P)^2+\cdots$ and hence it is a nonnegative matrix. So, if $a_1<a_2$, you should have $\left(a_1(I-\alpha P)\right)^{-1}\color{red}{\ge}\left(a_1(I-\alpha P)\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: @user1551 Understood, thanks for the reply, could you please change the variables $a_1$ and $a_2$ above? Thank you.